# Make a broadcastreceiver listening for events even when app is killed without service

Tags: java, android

I want my broadcastreceiver listenning for SMS incoming messages even when the app is killed.
I maked my app using a background service for keeping alive my BroadCastreeiver but that use a lot of battery.
So, I tried with IntentService but it seem the broadcastreceiver is killed in the same time of activity.

manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alpacah.persistentapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.alpacah.persistentapp.Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.alpacah.persistentapp.Handler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.alpacah.persistentapp.ProtectIntentService"></service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

BroadCastReceiver:

```
package com.alpacah.persistentapp;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Handler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ProtectIntentService.class));
        Log.e("BROADCASTRECEIVER", "Activated");
    }

}
```

Service:

```
package com.alpacah.persistentapp;

import android.app.Service;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class ProtectIntentService extends IntentService {

    public ProtectIntentService() {
        super("ProtectIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("handle", "intent");
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need a Service to keep your Receiver alive. Registering it in the manifest is sufficient. What problems are you having exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your response. My broadcastReceiver works fine until the activity is running: when I receive a sms, that call my service and log it. But when I kill the activity, nothing is working anymore.

Comment: Whether your Activity is running or not should have no effect on a statically registered Receiver getting its broadcast, as long as you're not disabling it somewhere. How are you determining that "nothing is working anymore"? I would point out that you're missing the `show()` call on the `Toast` in `Handler`'s `onReceive()` method.

Comment: Ok, I added the show(), tanks, but it still not displaying or logging anything in the log console when activity is killed. (The toast is now displayed when the app is alive)

Comment: What do you mean by "killed", exactly? If you're forcibly stopping your app, it's not going to be delivered that broadcast again until you next launch your Activity.

Comment: I just killing the activity by swipping if. I don't force stop it.

Comment: Well, I can't say this with any kind of certainty, but from what I gather from other users' similar problems, it seems there are certain devices that will put your app into a stopped state just from swiping it away. If yours functions correctly when navigating to the home screen or another app (without swiping your app away), then I would guess that maybe your device is one of those.

Comment: Ok so, on "normal" devices this code is supposed to work?

Comment: I can confirm that swiping an app away does not affect static SMS Receivers on any of my devices. They're Samsung, which is arguably "normal", I suppose.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But the weirdest thing is that receivers that catch BOOT_COMPLETED works correctly. (and my actual app that works with a permanent service works also with static sms broadcastreceiver)

Comment: That is slightly odd. Does your device have any extra permissions or settings, or perhaps a separate security-related app, that might be restricting certain functionalities? Maybe it's not putting your app in a stopped state, exactly, but rather marking it as "backgrounded" or something, and disallowing SMS?

Comment: I don't have any security app or extra settings :/ I gonna try with other actions.

Comment: Hmm, dunno. The only other thing I can think of to suggest at the moment would be to install another SMS app, and see if behaves the same as yours, just as a test of that device. Of course, if you could test on another device, or on an emulator, that'd be handy, too.

Comment: Ok, I tried and the same problem seems appears.

Comment: Which do you mean? The other SMS app stops working, too?

Comment: Yes. Maybe one of the application use an abortBroadcast?

Comment: Well, if that's the case, your app shouldn't ever get messages. Your Receiver's priority shouldn't change depending on whether it's been swiped or not. I can't say anything for certain, though, 'cause I've never worked with a device with that behavior. At least it's some reassurance that it's not just your code.

Comment: It's a little bit embarassing for make my tests x) I gonna search the cause, thanks you very much!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved; in my case I was using a Asus Zenphone2 and this one has a preinstalled app named Asus Mobile Manager that was blocking autostart programs.
I just autorizd my application and now, that works perfectly.
Go to Asus Mobile Manager  -> Autorizations -> Auto Start Manager -> allow your app